# Android Retrofit client + Spring Boot service POST "400" response

Tags: android, json, spring, spring-boot, retrofit

I'm writing Android (Kotlin) app with Spring Boot API/service (Java).
I have Retrofit client for Android and restful Spring Controller on the server.

The problem: when I make POST request with client-server JSON-serializable model provided below, service gives "400" (Bad Request).
Currenlty I don't have any chance to log Spring Boot's web/debug output on the server side, 
so the only things I can rely on and share are the client logs and actual project code.

This is Retrofit response object's log, nothing special:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=, url=https://my_url}
```

Here is Android client's model code (some fields with identical names are mutually renamed in both models to keep it simple):

```
class ClientPrivateUserTO(val serviceId: Int?,
                             val propOne: String?,
                             val propTwo: String,
                             val propThree: String,
                             val propFour: String?,
                             val ownAIds: Iterable<Int>,
                             val ownBIds: Iterable<Int>) : Serializable
```

Here is Retrofit client fun for request:

```
@POST("/add_update")
fun addOrUpdate(@Body userTo: ClientPrivateUserTO): Call<UserTransactionResponse>
```

Here is Spring service model class:

```
public class PrivateAppUserTO implements Serializable {

    private Integer serviceId;

    private String propOne;

    private String propTwo;

    private String propThree;

    private String propFour;

    private Iterable<Integer> ownAIds;

    private Iterable<Integer> ownBIds;

    public PrivateAppUserTO() {}

    public PrivateAppUserTO(@JsonProperty("serviceId") Integer serviceId, 
                            @JsonProperty("propOne") String propOne, 
                            @JsonProperty("propTwo") String propTwo, 
                            @JsonProperty("propThree") String propThree, 
                            @JsonProperty("propFour") String propFour,
                            @JsonProperty("ownAIds") Iterable<Integer> ownAIds, 
                            @JsonProperty("ownBIds") Iterable<Integer> ownBIds) {
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
        this.propOne = propOne;
        this.propTwo = propTwo;
        this.propThree = propThree;
        this.propFour = propFour;
        this.ownAIds = ownAIds;
        this.ownBIds = ownBIds;
    }

    public Integer getServiceId() {
        return serviceId;
    }

    public void setServiceId(Integer serviceId) {
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
    }

    public String getPropOne() {
        return propOne;
    }

    public void setPropOne(String propOne) {
        this.propOne = propOne;
    }

    public String getPropTwo() {
        return propTwo;
    }

    public void setPropTwo(String propTwo) {
        this.propTwo = propTwo;
    }

    public String getPropThree() {
        return propThree;
    }

    public void setPropThree(String propThree) {
        this.propThree = propThree;
    }

    public String getPropFour() {
        return propFour;
    }

    public void setPropFour(String propFour) {
        this.propFour = propFour;
    }

    public Iterable<Integer> getOwnAIds() {
        return ownAIds;
    }

    public void setOwnAIds(Iterable<Integer> ownAIds) {
        this.ownAIds = ownAIds;
    }

    public Iterable<Integer> getOwnBIds() {
        return ownBIds;
    }

    public void setOwnBIds(Iterable<Integer> ownBIds) {
        this.ownBIds = ownBIds;
    }
}
```

And here is service controller code:

```
@PostMapping(path="/add_update")
public @ResponseBody TransactionalResponseUserTO createOrUpdate(@RequestBody PrivateAppUserTO userTo) {
    if (userTo.getServiceId() == null) return userService.createFromClientServerUser(userTo);
    else return userService.updateFromClientServerUser(userTo);
}
```

Is there something done obviously wrong in the code above?

Could unwrapped Iterable<*> in model be the cause?

Are there some bottlenecks I should pay attention when writing client-server code on this stack?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that the reason was unwrapped `Iterable` - now when I switched to `List` wrapped in JSON object all works without problems.